# Recommended way to save audio stream to disk

Tags: flutter, audio-service

The audio_service package manages streaming audio from a URL. Is there a way to simultaneously write the audio to disk as well?

Note: In python, one [can do this](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-download-streaming-responses-as-a-file-in-python-51b52943f4e7) by setting `stream=True` when calling `requests` methods. I'm looking for a way to do this via a flutter package.

Comment: I suggest to use flutter sound package. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound

Comment: @KuKu Thanks! Can you point me to the documentation that allows saving the stream to disk in flutter_sound, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The audio_service package manages streaming audio from a URL.

audio_service doesn't manage streaming audio, it manages your media notification. The way it works is: let's say you **have already** written an app that plays audio using some plugin XYZ, but you want to now just add a media notification so that your app can be controlled from the background. Then you use audio_service to wrap around your "existing" audio code.

So your question is really about what to do for your existing audio code which audio_service wraps around.

If you are following the audio_service official example, it demonstrates using the just_audio plugin to stream audio from a URL, so let's answer in terms of that. You can easily modify the official example by using just_audio's `LockCachingAudioSource`.

So for example, whenever in that example you see `AudioSource.uri`, just replace that code with `LockCachingAudioSource` and it will do what you want. That's it.

But to demonstrate some of the capabilities of `LockCachingAudioSource` in a bit more detail, here is a short demo of the way it works:

```dart
final source = LockCachingAudioSource(Uri.parse(url));
await player.setAudioSource(source);
await player.play();
```

The location of the cache file is by default chosen by the plugin, but you can obtain it here:

```dart
final cacheFile = await source.cacheFile;
```

You can clear the cache with:

```dart
await source.clearCache();
```

If you want to choose the location of the cache file, you can do so when constructing the source:

```dart
final source = LockCachingAudioSource(
  Uri.parse(url),
  cacheFile: File('/your/preferred/path.mp3'),
);
```

Comment: I am using audio_service and just_audio player. I am using playlist.